# How the code below can be subjected to SQL Injection Attack to bypass the login mechanism

Tags: sql

How could the code below can be subjected to SQL Injection Attack to bypass the login mechanism

```
try {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE username = '"
                 + username.text + "' AND password = '" + pwd.text+ "'";
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql); 
}
```

Comment: `public boolean checkSecureLogin()`
  `{`
      `boolean bool = false;`

      `Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from login where " +
          `"USERNAME = ? and PASSWORD = ?", new String[]{});`

      `if (cursor != null) {`
          `if (cursor.moveToFirst())`
               `bool = true;`
          `cursor.close();`
      `}`
      `return bool;`
  `}`


referance from [Here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2268753&seqNum=5)

Answer (score 1):

Analyze the following SQL statement and state how the hacker can manipulate the given query to access confidential information from the website, such as user’s details (username, password, credit card details, etc.) from a simple select statement commonly used in the website search text box.

```sql
Select * from items where item_name Like ‘itemTextbox.text’;
```

Answer (score 0):

Let the user enter the following (have an eye on the single quote and the commenting dashes):

```
FakeUserName'; DROP TABLE employee; SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('FakeUserName')) as employee (username) --
```

Well, ok, suppose that he knows a username, he just has to enter `ThatUsername' --` and no matter what password.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But what part of the original code would allow an attacker to bypass the login mechanism. Thanks

Comment: @CostomXRodriguez If you just insert the user enties, say `UserName` and `Pa$$w0rd`, the SQL will be: `SELECT * FROM employee WHERE username = 'UserName' AND password = 'Pa$$w0rd'`. This will work as expected. If the user instead entered `UserName' --` and `Pa$$w0rd`, the query would be `SELECT * FROM employee WHERE username = 'UserName' --' AND password = 'Pa$$w0rd'`. Everything behind the dashes will be ignored, so the "effective" query reads `SELECT * FROM employee WHERE username = 'UserName'`, so the password will be ignored.

Comment: @CostomXRodriguez  To avoid this, you could simply replace every single-qoute entered by 2 single-qoutes before assembling the query.

Comment: It's worth noting that this kind of attack wouldn't work with Oracle as the JDBC driver will refuse to run more than one statement with a single `execute()` call

Comment: To avoid this the only sensible solution is to use a `PreparedStatement`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Oracle will refuse to execute `SELECT * FROM employee WHERE username = 'UserName' -- some comment`? Well, then on Oracle systems, there's nothing to worry about (but maybe that nothing is executed). The question in the OP wasn't on how to avoid this kind of attack, it was on how to attack that code, so a "solution" is to show how to perform SQL injection when the code is written as in the request. So, although you might think it's worthless, maybe @CostomXRodriguez will value my reply. Nevertheless, please give me a hint on how the single-quote replacement is vulnerable.

Comment: Oracle will refuse to run a SQL string that contains a `;` to separate multiple statements. So the "usual" attack with `'; drop table users;` won't work. Adding a comment to the end of the statement won't change the statement nor will it allow any exploit. And I never said it's worthless. The OP didn't mention any specific DBMS, for other JDBC drivers that **is** a vulnerability that can be exploited. While escaping single quotes will work, using a PreparedStatement is still the better (and recommended) solution. For performance reasons and things like "date formats"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sorry for misunderstanding your "It's worth noting" and thanks for the explanation about JDBC. The comment thing in the end wasn't ment to allow or avoid any exploit, it **IS** the exploit. If the user enters `ThatUsername' --` (with the commenting dashes in the end of his input), the `AND password = 'AnyPa$$w0rd''` part of the select statement will be ignored (as a comment), which is how the attacker can bypass the login mechanism. Also, thanks for the hint on the recommended and better way with a prepared statement. I knew that and just said that one **could** do... :-)